# delete a row using column field name - SQlite (SQLiteOpenHelper Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I need to delete a row in database (SQLite)

I am trying to delete a row using the file name. File is a field in the database column.

```
public void deleteRow (String file){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("checkList", "DELETE FROM checkList Where file = "+file, null);
}
```

What I get is:

> Process: com.example.operacioneschecklist, PID: 29351
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "DELETE": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: DELETE FROM checkList WHERE DELETE FROM checkList Where file = SE 062 Merlo20:05:23:12.txt

This is the class code That I implemented:

```
class MyDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 1;

    private static final String NAME = "checkList.db";

    private static final String TABLA_CHECK_LIST = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checkList" +
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, file TEXT, se TEXT, date TEXT, aux TEXT)";

    public MyDB(Context context) {
        super(context, NAME, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLA_CHECK_LIST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checkList");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean deleteDB(Context context) {
        return context.deleteDatabase(NAME);
    }

    public void insert(String file, String se, String date, String aux) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("file", file);
            valores.put("se", se);
            valores.put("date", date);
            valores.put("aux", aux);
            db.insert("checkList", null, valores);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public List<String> loadHandler() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "Select*FROM checkList";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int result_0 = cursor.getInt(0);
            String result_1 = cursor.getString(1);
            String result_2 = cursor.getString(2);
            String result_3 = cursor.getString(3);
            String result_4 = cursor.getString(4);

            list.add(result_1 + "%:&" + result_2 + "%:&" + result_3 + "%:&" + result_4);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return list;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        String query = "Select*FROM checkList";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public void deleteFirstRow() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String where = "id < (select id from checkList order by id limit 15, 1)";
        db.delete("checkList", where, null);
    }

    public void orderIt() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("VACUUM");
    }

    public String getLastHash() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select*FROM checkList";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToLast();
        return cursor.getString(1);
    }

    public void deleteRow(String file) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("checkList", "DELETE FROM checkList Where file = " + file, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the 2nd argument of `delete()` you use the full sql statement, which is not nedeed and you concatenate the variable `file` to the sql statement's string without surrounding it with single quotes.
But even if you did, it is not the safe and recommended way.
Pass the parameter `file` in the 3d argument of the method `delete()` and use a `?` placeholder inside the sql statement which will be replaced by the value of `file`, properly quoted, when the statement will be parsed:

```
db.delete("checkList", "file = ?", new String[] {file});
```

The 2nd argument of `delete()` is the `WHERE` clause without the keyword `WHERE`.

Comment: How can I use 2 columns to delete? I mean delete a row based on a file column value and another one by yourself?

Comment: With this: `db.delete("checkList", "file = ? and anothercolumn = ?", new String[] {file, anothercolumnvalue});`